# Frontend JSON payload that defines which classes to use in the backend

Tags: java, c#, json

Payload:

```js
{
    "selection": {
        "ids": [1,2,3,4,5]
    },
    "image": {
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "headlineColor": "#000000",
        "format": "PNG"
    },
    "processors": [
        {
            "repository": "org.my.world.app.repositories.RepoX",    // fetch data from this Repository
            "builder": "org.my.world.app.builders.ModelBuilderA"    // use this ModelBuilder with the fetched data
        },
        {
            "repository": "org.my.world.app.repositories.RepoX",
            "builder": "org.my.world.app.builders.ModelBuilderB"
        },
        {
            "repository": "org.my.world.app.repositories.RepoY",
            "builder": "org.my.world.app.builders.ModelBuilderA"
        },
        {
            "repository": "org.my.world.app.repositories.RepoY",
            "builder": "org.my.world.app.builders.ModelBuilderB"
        }
    ]
}
```

This payload generates a result based on the 5 provided `ids` `[1,2,3,4,5]`. The 5 `ids` are fed trough each defined `processor`. Each `processor` object is a definition of how each individual `id` is processed.
The payload is send as a POST request to a specific REST endpoint. e.g.: `http://org.my.world/generate/result`

Currently in the application I try to instantiate the class with the provided class path or check for an exisiting class with the given class path.

```java
public interface Repo {
    Model readId( int id );
}

@Inject RepoX repoX;
@Inject RepoY repoY;

public Model fetchModel(id) {

    Model model = new Model();

    if ( repository.equalsIgnoreCase( RepoX.class.toString() ) ) {
        model = repoX.readId( id );
    }
    else if ( repository.equalsIgnoreCase( RepoY.class.toString() ) ) {
        model = repoY.readId( id );
    }

    return model;
}
```

As soon as more repositories are added, to the app, the bigger the if(switch) statement gets. Is there a better way to this?
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried indexing or listing repositories?

Comment: @Laiv could you elaborate a bit on what you are suggesting?